# Есть 2 формы, как объединить их input text?

Tags: html, input

Есть 2 формы, как объединить их input text? Чтобы было 1 общее поле ввода для двух форм

```html
<button id="button1" title="" onclick="
setTimeout('x1.submit()',  100 );
setTimeout('x2.submit()',  100 );

"> Выполнить</button>


<form method="post" action="http://....." name="x1" target="y1">
<input type="hidden" name=one>
<input type="hidden" name=two>
<input type="hidden" name=three>
<input type="text" name="action"  value="">
</form>

<form method="post" action="http://....." name="x2" target="y1">
<input type="hidden" name=one>
<input type="hidden" name=two>
<input type="hidden" name=three>
<input type="text" name="action"  value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, можно просто присвоить значение одного input другому:

```js
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

document.addEventListener('input',function(){
inp[1].value = inp[0].value

});
```

```html
<form >

<input type="text" name="action"  value="">
</form>

<form >
<input type="text" name="action"  value="">
</form>
```